# android studio preview not rendering my changes

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to do this example from Android Developer course for Happy birthday, but in my preview screen it never renders the 'from bob'.

This is the the stage I am at:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables#6

```
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier= Modifier){
    Row {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 110.sp
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            lineHeight = 20.sp

        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        GreetingText(message ="Happy Birthday Android", from = "from bob")
    }
}
```

And on the preview screen it only shows Happy Birthday Android, but the 'from bob' is missing. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob is there, he just doesn't fit the window because the greetings mesage fills it up entirely.
Reduce the `fontSize` of the message to `20.sp`, for example, and Bob will return.

Comment: awesome that worked, why didn't it resize the box to fit the two lines? how did it decide what was the as big as it gets?